# Finding nearest neighbours in 3d point cloud, GPU

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, gpu, gpgpu, nearest-neighbor

I want to calculate nearest neighbors for every point in a point cloud via GPU. 
My data set looks like:

```
<number of points in column>
<number of columns>

x   y   z
x   y   z
z   y   z
... ... ...
```

There are nearly 20^6 points.
I am using `vector<PointXYZ> Input;` to store data with

```
class PointXYZ
{
public:
    PointXYZ();
    ~PointXYZ();
    PointXYZ(float X, float Y, float Z) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z) {};

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

};
```

Reading data is in a for loop, which ignore points where there is no information ( x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0).

```
PointXYZ* NewPoint = new PointXYZ(x, y, z);
Input.push_back(*NewPoint);
```

And here are my questions:

1. What is the best input structure to read the data before sending it to GPU? (Current reading takes about 120s).
2. I do not have proper indexes of point in 2d image (because I am ignoring points without information). Every point contains x,y,z values. What would be the most accurate, but not so advanced algorithm to find 3/6/9 nearest neighbors? Is linear comparison (brute force) for that number of points via GPU is not efficient?

I was looking at octrees but I am not sure how point cloud can be divided without proper indexes.

Comment: you can `reserve(...)` your vector for the final number of elements it will contain, to allocate once only. That will speed up things. Also if you want to speed things up even further, use a binary data format for your data set, it will be smaller

Comment: Are you sure about 20^6 points? That's about 64 million, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I just did some tests. I used a somewhat clustered 3D dataset with 10'000'000 points. Implementations are in Java, I used my [qthypercube2](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes) implementation.

1. For my tests I often store data in a database as a large float[] BLOB. Loading 10'000'000 points into memory takes about 0.5 second.
2. Loading the data into a quadtree (I use my own special implementation) takes about 4 seconds.
3. Performing 1'000'000 3-NN searches takes about 20 seconds, that would be about 200 seconds or 3.3 minutes for 10'000'000 3-N searches.

I never used GPUs but lets do some math:
I assume by "brute force" you mean comparing every point to every other point? 10^7 point that means 10^14 comparison operations. Each comparison taking 10 cycles (just to have a number) means 10^15 computing cycles. Let's say the GPU allows 1000 operations be performed in parallel, that still means 10^12 cycles. If your GPU is clocked at 1GHz (10^9 ops per second), the total search would be 10^12/10^9 = 10^3 = 1000 seconds.
This does not take into account: Loading data into GPU, storing the (intermediate) nearest neighbors, sorting the intermediate result (if it is more than 1NN), ...

Of course the specifics of your GPU and NN-search implementations may be different, as may be the actual size of your data set. All of that may reduce or increase these 1000 second.
Also for the quadtree, the dataset characteristics (clustering, etc...) may play a big role, as may be the type of search (I tested 3 nearest neighbors). Also my implementation is 'general purpose' in the sense that it works for any dimensionality. A dedicated 3D implementation may be faster.

My guess: At 10M points, using a quadtree should be faster than a GPU version, and *definitely* easier to implement.